# How to input data into struct that is being pointed by another struct

Tags: c++

I have been trying to figure out how to input data from a file to structure.
I have nailed the part with one struct, but I have trouble with assignig values to stuff like that: `tab[i].attack->name`. How to input that data properly?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

const int size = 2;

struct spell
{
    char name[20];
    int power;
};

struct person
{
    char name[20];
    char surname[50];
    int powerlevel;
    spell* attack;
};

void writeInput(person tab[])
{
    fstream file("input.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        file >> tab[i].powerlevel >> tab[i].name >> tab[i].surname >> tab[i].attack->name >> tab[i].attack->power;
    }
}
    
void readInput(person tab[])
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout<<tab[i].powerlevel<<" "<<tab[i].name<<" "<<tab[i].surname<<tab[i].attack->name<<" "<<tab[i].attack->power<<endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    person tab[size];
    writeInput(tab);
    readInput(tab);
    
}
```

Comment: The data member spell* attack; is uninitialized. It points nowhere.

Comment: Omg, yes, what a stupid mistake. Thank you so much <3

Comment: Note that you want to **always** verify that reading input was successful before using the result. For me this typically looks like `if (file >> ...) { use_input(); } else { deal_with_input_failure(); }`.